# Center header image in jquerymobile header

Tags: jquery, css, html

My header is left aligned, even though I intend it to be centred. Heres my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="first">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div >
            <img style="margin:0 auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;align:center;"  onclick='doAction("showStoreLocatorMap()")' src="images/main_header.png" alt="main logo" vspace="2"/>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="firstPageContent"> 
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only this can do the job:

```
<div align="center">
     <img  onclick='doAction("showStoreLocatorMap()")' src="images/main_header.png" alt="main logo" vspace="2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the image inside any header tags, I had the same problem and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS to the outer `div` of the `img`.

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <img onclick='doAction("showStoreLocatorMap()")' src="images/main_header.png" alt="main logo" vspace="2"/>
</div>
```